# Migrating Theme from MOSS 2007 to 2010

Tags: deployment

Can any of the post readers help me out how to make my moss 2007 custom theme work in sharepoint 2010.

Thanks in Advance
Manoj

Answer (score 2):

Your theme cannot work in 2010 unless you use the visual upgrade view. If you are deploying to a new environment, you will need to create the theme in the same location as in the MOSS environment. If you are upgrading using a content database attach, then it will automatically show in the MOSS view with the theme applied. If you are creating new sites in 2010 and want to do this, you will have to use a PowerShell command and set it to show in the MOSS view instead of 2010. The PowerShell command can be found here: http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=56f96349%2D3bb6%2D4087%2D94f4%2D7f95ff4ca81f&ID=173&Web=48e6fdd1%2D17db%2D4543%2Db2f9%2D6fc7185484fc.

You can only show a MOSS theme in this manner as the masterpages and page layouts use completely different CSS classes than 2010. Themes in 2010 are completely different, all they do is change a few colors and fonts for you.

You should be aware that if you use the MOSS view instead of the upgrade to 2010 you will lose some functionality. I would suggest taking the CSS you have for your theme and work on upgrading it to work with 2010 and creating a custom masterpage to call this alternate CSS. You can then install this as a solution and activate it on multiple sites using a PowerShell command.

Answer (score -2):

Create new theme in [PowerPoint](http://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBoQFjAA&url=http://www.sharepointedutech.com/2010/02/15/using-powerpoint-2010-themes-in-sharepoint-2010-in-6-easy-steps/&ei=gJ4RTtSgCczQsga28amWDw&usg=AFQjCNEL9NeMJnMkzNtqCdziy7xgScfkNA&sig2=U8ugBDCg5S6GgFw866QpNw)